# VS Code output of Jupyter Notebook not showing

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Not sure why but I have not tweaked anything in the settings.  The Python environment is successfully loaded and I can execute the code but the output of my code is not showing. I'd like to display the output for instance, "4" below my code as what you can normally find in Jupyter.

[output of Python code compressed and not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6AUz.png)

I already restarted my VS Code but it still works the same. Anyone help with this?

Comment: weird... cell outputs can be collapsed, but when they are, they show a message saying so, which clicking will cause the output to be re-expanded, which is not what is shown in your screenshot...

Comment: if you can reproduce this issue easily and consistently, then I'd suggest that you also raise an issue ticket, such as was done before in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/13652, and to avoid having a similar fate as that one, provide as much info as you can about how to easily and consistently reproduce the issue in your issue ticket. if you do raise an issue ticket, please ping me here with a link to it.

Comment: Was it working normally before? Click the three dots to the left of the results to see what options are available?

Answer (score 0):

1. Examine the settings for output visibility: Make that the output visibility settings are set correctly. The outputs can be chosen to be shown or hidden. Locate the cell visibility control choices (represented by an eye-shaped icon) in the toolbar. Make sure that the output is displayed.
2. **Recent Additions:** Verify that the Jupyter and VS Code extensions are current. Compatibility problems could arise from outdated extensions.
3. *Start VS Code again* Restarting Visual Studio Code can occasionally resolve unforeseen problems as a final option.

If none of these fixes work, there may be some underlying problems with your configuration that require more research or sophisticated troubleshooting.